# Executing curl command with ProcessBuilder and bearer token

Tags: java, curl, processbuilder, bearer-token

I am trying to execute a curl PUT request which contains a bearer token for the authorization header, using ProcessBuilder. There is some issue with how ProcessBuilder is parsing the quotes for the header and I can't figure out how to write the curl command.
This is the command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" -T kubernetes.hpi -X PUT "https://<url>"
```

I've seen some solutions where not putting quotes was helpful, but in this case the header contains spaces so that doesn't work for me. For the header, I've tried single quotes, escaping double quotes, no quotes, etc.

I either get a 401 error

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Unauthorized"
} ]
```

or I get errors from curl

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

How can I write the command so that it works with ProcessBuilder? The command works in the command line, but I get errors from curl with ProcessBuilder.

```
String deployPath =
    String.format(
        "%s%s/%s_%s/%s.hpi;ID=%s",
        artifactoryLocalRepoUrl,
        pluginName,
        jenkinsPluginDetail.getPluginVersion(),
        currUTCMillis,
        pluginName,
        jenkinsPluginDetail.getId().toString());
String[] deployArtifactCmd =
        new String[] {
          "curl",
          "-T",
          outputPath,
                "-X",
                "PUT",
                deployPath,
                "-H",
                "\'Authorization: Bearer " + bearerToken + "\'"
        };
    
    logger.info(" Executing deploying plugin {}", pluginName);
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder2 =
        new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(deployArtifactCmd).redirectErrorStream(true);
    logger.info(processBuilder2.command().toString());
    try {
       Process process = processBuilder2.start();
       ...
```

Comment: It would help if you add the full error message or exception.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're using a third party app at all when the JRE now has quite a powerful http client..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters passed to `ProcessBuilder` should not need quote characters. Your shell would strip them when passing on the command line to `curl`. Your last parameter has quotes so try without the quotes:

```
"Authorization: Bearer " + bearerToken
```

The quotes are needed in shell so that it recognises spaces as continuation of a parameter value. They are unnecessary in Java as you can supply a value with spaces in the array of arguments.

Comment: that worked.. thank you. I guess the trick was to have this header at the end of the command so that the spaces were not an issue.

Comment: @SS123 I've amended slightly - the fix to remove quotes applies regardless of the parameter index. Hope that is clearer now.